# Javascript Validation - How do I check that the number entered into a form is between a certain range?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have this part of a html code:

```
<tr>
    <td id="examnumber">Examination number</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="examnumber"/></td>
</tr>
```

And I need the number entered to be 4 digits long and between the range 0000-9999. I have attempted to validate it by using this javascript code:

```
function validateForm() {
         var result = true;
         var msg="";


         if (document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value=="") {
           msg+="You must enter your examination number. \n";
           document.ExamEntry.examnumber.focus();
           document.getElementById('examnumber').style.color="red";
         } else if ((document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value.length < 0) ||       (document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value.length > 9999)) {
           msg+= "The examination number is not within the range 0000-9999.\n";
           result = false
         }

        if (document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value.length!=4) {
          msg+="Your examination number must be 4 digits long. \n";
          document.ExamEntry.examnumber.focus();
          document.getElementById('examnumber').style.color="red";
          result = false;
        }
```

However when I test the code by entering -900 or 3.45, it doesn't come up with an error message and says that the information has been entered correctly. I would very much appreciate it if someone could help me to fix this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue here is the field is named `examnumber` which you're trying to get it by going through the form name (Presumably `ExamEntry`). Getting a reference to the field in this way(`document.Form_Name.Field_Name`) is out-dated and only ever really worked on Internet Explorer.

A more generic way is using [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById).

You are using this, in this line:

```
document.getElementById('examnumber').style.color="red";
```

But `examnumber` is the field name, not the Id. You should add an id to the field as well:

```
<td><input type="text" name="examnumber" id="examnumberfield"/></td>
```

This will enable you to use throughout:

```
var examnumberlabel = document.getElementById("examnumber");
var examnumberfield = document.getElementById("examnumberfield");
if (examnumberfield.value=="") {
       msg+="You must enter your examination number. \n";
       examnumberfield.focus();
       examnumberlabel .style.color="red";
//.. etc
```

(I suggest that a simple regex test on the value can both validate the length, and numeric status of the value - no need for separate tests.)

Comment: "examnumber" is also the id of <td>.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^\d{4}$/.test(document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value)
```

This Regexp will return true if it contains exactly 4 digits (0-9).